# Spark 1.6, DataFrame: fill gaps by adding rows

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame that looks like follow:

```
+-----+---+-----+
|  id |ind| freq|
+-----+---+-----+
|user1|  1|    5|
|user2|  0|   13|
|user2|  2|    4|
|user3|  2|    7|
|user3|  3|   45|
+-----+---+-----+
```

The column `ind` has integer values that range between 0 and 3.

I would like to add the missing `ind` values for each user, while filling the `freq` columns with default value such as 0, so the output DataFrame looks like follow:

```
+-----+---+-----+
|  id |ind| freq|
+-----+---+-----+
|user1|  0|    0|
|user1|  1|    5|
|user1|  2|    0|
|user1|  3|    0|
|user2|  0|   13|
|user2|  1|    0|
|user2|  2|    4|
|user2|  3|    0|
|user3|  0|    0|
|user3|  1|    0|
|user3|  2|    7|
|user3|  3|   45|
+-----+---+-----+
```

What is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: I'm voting this is up because it gets messy doing this with Spark... :)

Comment: Did you solve this question Rami ?

Comment: Hi eliasah, I have completely changed my strategy, so I am no longer using this anymore, but your solution was correct, as you said, it might need some optimisation. thanks

Comment: You are welcome ! You are using that to fill gaps on a time series ?

Comment: yes, it can be for filling gaps between dates :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the best solution one can come up with, but from the top of my head, it will do the job :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row


val df = sc.parallelize(List(("user1",1,5),("user2",  0,   13),("user2",  2,   4),("user3",  2,    7),("user3",  3,   45))).toDF("id","ind","freq")
df.show

// +-----+---+----+
// |   id|ind|freq|
// +-----+---+----+
// |user1|  1|   5|
// |user2|  0|  13|
// |user2|  2|   4|
// |user3|  2|   7|
// |user3|  3|  45|
// +-----+---+----+

val df2 = df.groupBy('id).pivot("ind").max("freq").na.fill(0)
df2.show

// +-----+---+---+---+---+
// |   id|  0|  1|  2|  3|
// +-----+---+---+---+---+
// |user1|  0|  5|  0|  0|
// |user2| 13|  0|  4|  0|
// |user3|  0|  0|  7| 45|
// +-----+---+---+---+---+

val cols = df2.columns

val df3 = df2.rdd.map {
  case r : Row =>
    val id = r.getAs[String]("id")
    cols.map(ind => (id,ind,r.getAs[Integer](ind)))
}.flatMap(_.toSeq).filter(_._2 != "id").toDF("id","ind","freq")

df3.show

// +-----+---+----+
// |   id|ind|freq|
// +-----+---+----+
// |user1|  0|   0|
// |user1|  1|   5|
// |user1|  2|   0|
// |user1|  3|   0|
// |user2|  0|  13|
// |user2|  1|   0|
// |user2|  2|   4|
// |user2|  3|   0|
// |user3|  0|   0|
// |user3|  1|   0|
// |user3|  2|   7|
// |user3|  3|  45|
// +-----+---+----+
```

I'm using the `pivot` function from `GroupeData` then I flatten it by column. **(Spark 1.6+)**

**PS:** This solution is not optimized and my have lots of drawbacks. i.e : large number of indices, computational cost, etc.

Comment: Any other suggestions to do this in a more effective way?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this "gap" problem and the solution I came up with is naive, so it may be not efficient, but I think it's very straight-forward.

Basically to exhaust all the combination of `(id, ind)` pairs, from the original DF I select distinct values of `id` and again select distinct values of `ind`, then cross join these two results to get all combinations. After that simply join the outcome back to the original DF and fill all NA with 0.